How to add Image (png) to R Shiny App in the title/header?
I was trying to add a image to my r shiny app, but the image doesn't want to show up when I run the app.
I've tried this line of code:
ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = bs_theme(preset = "spacelab"),
  titlePanel(
    div(class = "header",
        img(src = "Steam_icon_logo.png", class = "logo"),  # Logo image
        div(class = "title", "Game Recommender")    # Title text
    ),
  ),

The image directory is correct but when the app runs the images shows as the attached screenshot.


Is the image in the www/ directory? That's the standard directory where images need to be placed to be accessible using the path you've used.

Here is a solution I came up with:

I created a www directory in the main app directory and stored the image in that folder.

I defined the height and width of the image in the img() function so that it does not take up all the space.


Here is the corrected code:
ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = bslib::bs_theme(preset = "spacelab"),
  titlePanel(
    div(class = "header",
        img(src = "plot.png", height = 100, width = 150),  # Logo image
        div(class = "title", "Game Recommender Histogram")    # Title text
    ),
  ),


Now, the image appears exactly where you want it. You can play around with the height and width parameters of img() further if you wish. I hope this helps!
